# JSPack fails to convert double to bytes

Tags: javascript, floating-point, double, byte, ieee-754

I'm trying to use [JSPack](https://github.com/pgriess/node-jspack) to convert from double to array of octets.

This code:

```
jsp = new JSPack();
t = jsp.Pack("d", 2.0);
```

results in `t` being the array `[127, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/pgriess/node-jspack) says:

> Pack(fmt, values)
>
> Return an octet array containing the packed values **array**.

Indeed:

```
new JSPack().Pack("d", [2])
```

returns:

```
[64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which seems correct (I get the same result with typed arrays: `Float64Array` to `Uint8Array`).